# Change in matrix of features format after one hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with 10 independent variables (2 categorical and 8 numerical) and one dependent variable. I used one hot encoding on the categorical dataset and the multiple linear regression algorithm worked fine.

However, I want to check for the same without 2 of the numerical variables. So I changed `X = dataset.iloc[:,[3,17,18,20,23,24,25,26,27,28]].values` to `X = dataset.iloc[:,[3,17,18,20,23,24,26,28]].values`.

But now after encoding the categorical values, the matrix of features x looks like

```
(0, 6)  1.0
...
(0, 23) 1.0
```

instead of

```
[0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 34 95 2905]
...
[0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 74 29 3819]
```

This resulted in an error while splitting the dataset into a test set and training set:

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(<1104x29 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 8832 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

Why does this error occur when I only made a small change in the code?

Comment: you might be forgetting to update the index of to columns to apply the onehotencoding. Are you using pipelines? Can you give more code details?

Comment: @JulioJesus no i am not using pipelines. the only difference is the index values